# Is black metal without cult of evil esthetics still black metal

Tags: genre, metal

Does trebly distorted guitar with a lot of tremolo picking and dissonant intervals can be called black metal no matter what subject it refers? Or it is another genre then?

Some genres definitions like Anarcho-punk are more about lyrics than music itself

Comment: >"Does trebly distorted guitar with a lot of tremolo picking and dissonant intervals can be called black metal" — nope, composition matters too. it's hard to describe though, I don't know much music theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is a little bit subjective and depends on whether you perceive a music genre from it's music only or from the lyrics and the whole aesthetics too. I as a musician only listen to the music to define what genre I am listening to.

An interesting experiment was done by StevieT in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq8ODuozdIo) video where he tried to play happy black metal. Is it black metal for you or not? I think it is completely subjective.

Comment: This video has two versions inside and none of it sound black metal to me

Comment: But I checked other bands and they also doesn't sound black metal to me so I think you actually answered the question. Black metal is more about band declaration than identified music it is not possible to easy distinguish it from other extreme metal genres

Comment: I agree. For example the band 'Thorns' has space themes. Somebody could say that it is not black metal but it gets listed into that category

Comment: Check out Dream Theater "A Nightmare to Remember" . This is a pure musical experiment, an attempt to sound like black/death/doom (elements of each).

Comment: My favorite black act is Dimmu Borgir, and they are considered 'false' by the 'true black' community. I do not care.

Comment: @TimSparrow Dream theater is one of my favourite bands. They play progressive metal and by definition it can incorporate any genre they like. :D

Comment: @papakias exactly. This is about music craftmanship, not ideology.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is, for Black Metal features a variety of recurring motifs: Except for the esthetics of evil and satanism, space (Thorns, Mare Cognitum), nihilism/senselesness/despair (Mgla, Shining) winter (Paysage D'hiver) and archaic nature (Cascadian Black Metal in general) are themes that frequently crop up in Black Metal.